# How to plot an histogram with qacBase package

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw a histogram with qacBase package.
My data frame contains Spotify chart data. (language, rank, region, ...)
Language1 is a character variable.

```
library(qacBase)
library(tidyverse)
histograms(data = spotify_lang$Language1 , fill = "skyblue", color = "white", bins = 20)
```

when I run my code I get this error:

```
    Error in UseMethod("gather") : 
        no applicable method for 'gather' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I would really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a short, representative sample of your data. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of the `dput(data)` command (preferred) or in tab delimited form. This will help users here answer your question.

Comment: The `histograms()` `data=` parameter needs to be a data.frame, not a character vector. What if you just did `histograms(data = spotify_lang , fill = "skyblue", color = "white", bins = 20)` or `histograms(data = spotify_lang[, "Language1", drop=FALSE] , fill = "skyblue", color = "white", bins = 20)`